# Quite over (the?) 10%

Tags: word-usage, determiners

Let's say a graph shows a percentage above 10%. 
Would it be correct to say:

> *Quite* over *the* 10%.

I'm not sure if "*quite*" is ok in this context, and I'm wondering if "*the*" could be used in case 10% is somehow important: for example it may be the higher value in the chart (while **not** having "something graphical" different).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **above** instead of **over** since there is above/below directions in a graph

> The graph is **above** 10%, showing a value **over** 10%

To describe a number **much greater than 10%**, you could say

> **quite** above 10%
>   **very much** above 10%
>   **well** over 10%
>   **significantly** above 10%

**Quite** is more a BrE term than an AmE term meaning **much**.

You would use **the** if **10%** was used as an adjective

> **the** 10% level
>   **the** 10% mark

Only using **the 10%** would not have any meaning by itself, and **articles** are not usually used for **plain numbers** but for cardinal and ordinal numbers.

Comment: I would avoid the word 'quite' as it's a bit of a minefield.  It's used differently in BrE and AmE, and in BrE it can mean different things depending on the emphasis you put on the word.  The other options are clear and unambiguous whoever you're talking to.

Comment: @ssav +1 Quite. *(BrE meaning)* :)

Comment: @ssav - I'm not sure that I'd go so far as to say "avoid" the word quite, although you're correct to point out that the word's meaning can morph a little bit (or quite a bit?) depending on the usage and context.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the word "well" as in `well over 10%` if what you mean that it is not just barely over 10% but perhaps something like 15%